# Error in delopyment in from Xamarin forms to Xamarin.Andorid

Tags: c#, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

Hi I am using Xamarin forms to write Android and iOS App

As far as I understand, in order to create a notification I need to write directly to the projects of Xamarin.Andorid and Xamarin.IOS.

However, when I started writing to the Xamarin.Andorid I probably removed something by mistake and it does not recognize `APP()`
though my application call Maya, and I get an error in deploying the project

```
1>Unexpected install output:    pkg: /data/local/tmp/Maya.Android-Signed.apk
1>Failure [INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_MANIFEST_MALFORMED]
```

Here is my main Activity code:

```
using System;
using Android.App;  
using Android.Content.PM;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.OS;   

namespace Maya.Droid
{
[Activity(Label = "Maya", Icon = "@drawable/icon", Theme = "@style/MainTheme", MainLauncher = true, ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation)]
public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
        ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;

        base.OnCreate(bundle);

        global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, bundle);
        LoadApplication(new App());
    }
}   
}
```

Comment: So you don't even use any source code control system such as Git?

Comment: no I am not using why??

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Version_control Learn to use such tools and next time you don't even need to ask such questions. Simply revert to a previous working copy and everything can work again.

Comment: Have you register the permission "<uses-permission android:name="yourpackagename.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />" ?